# temporal "directly" in AmEng usage: "immediately/without delay" or "shortly/in a little while"?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, formality, vernacular, dialectal

What does ***directly*** commonly mean in standard AmEng when used as a temporal adverb,

***immediately/instantly/at once/right away/without delay***

-or-

***soon/shortly/in a little while***?

> DIRECTLY
>
> At once; instantly: *Leave directly*.
>
> ***Chiefly Southern US*** In a little while; shortly: *He'll be coming directly* (emphasis is mine.)
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/directly)
>
> At once; without delay.
>
> Shortly; soon.
>
> **Usage note**:
>
> *immediately*, *instantly*, *directly*, *presently* were once close synonyms, all denoting complete absence of delay or any lapse of time. *immediately* and *instantly* still almost always have that sense and usu. mean *at once*: *He got up immediately*. *She responded instantly to the request*. *directly* is usu. equivalent to *soon*, *in a little while* rather than *at once*: *You go ahead, we'll join you directly*.
>
> [Random House Kennerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/immediately)

Please, consider:

> *Have a seat, Dr. Campbell will be with you directly.*
>
> *She fell asleep directly after she went to bed.*

Does that mean,

> *Dr. Campbell will be right with you/will be with you right away/with no delay.*
>
> *She fell asleep immediately/right after she went to bed.*

-or-

> *Dr. Campbell will be with you shortly/soon/in a little while.*
>
> *She fell asleep shortly/soon after she went to bed.*

Comment: This is probably a concessive interpretation. _Directly_ and _immediately_ 'were once close synonyms', but 'Mr X will be with you directly' often had a truth value of zero. Because _shortly_ /  _as soon as he is able to be_ were more accurate temporal expressions, the 'directly' usage broadened to include these. Possibly regrettable, but typical.

Comment: In that case, we'd have to go through the dictionary and update quite a few words: **shortly**, **few** (as in 'a few minutes'), **momentarily**. We'd also have to change "unusual" to mean "usual", as in "We're experiencing unusually high call volumes." I have never *not* gotten that message when calling certain companies over a 20-year period :)

Comment: I don't think it is a temporal adverb. It actually addresses sequence or priority when used as a sentential adverb. It's aspect is that the action will be begun next, and will be continued with out any dallying. If you know the context, you should be able to form an estimate of the time involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Directly* should mean "right away" – "with no delay" – as we (want to) take it usually.

But, as it's not exactly a "now", that means your Dr Campbell is currently at that time doing something else. So if Dr Campbell has a hard time on what he is doing now, it may take a while before you see him.

For ex. you may not see him before 50 minutes because it depends how much time it takes your dentist (Yes ! Brandon Campbell is a dentist in Barstow near Orlando, Fl.) to end what he is doing actually to meet you immediatly after, directly.

*Directly* means **as soon as possible** with no garantee of time limit.

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. RHK Webster's (above) says: 'directly is usu. equivalent to soon, in a little while rather than at once'. Why should we want to use it in a less usual way than most people (Webster's basing their data on decent surveys) do? And 'as we take it usually' obviously contradicts the Webster's findings.

Comment: Because each word is an idiom. Dictionnary are only definitionS that freeze the sense of the expresison we use. You may not take a word like I do because you, I and our vocabulary are living to express the life. The main goal is to understand each other, not at 100% but at 51%. So what I wrote above doesn't contradict Webster as "soon" may be 3 seconds to   minutes....

Comment: '_Directly_ should mean "right away" as we take it usually' certainly contradicts '_directly_ is usually [**not**] equivalent to _at once_'.

Answer (score 1):

As you have stated, this is another Southernism.

Though it may have been widely used at one time, 'directly' in this context is most often used today in the Southeastern region of the United States. It usually means something along the lines of 'soon' or 'shortly' or 'as soon as possible.' Your example,

> Have a seat, Dr. Campbell will be with you directly.

could be rewritten as

> Have a seat, Dr. Campbell will be with you *as soon as he is able.*

or

> Have a seat, Dr. Campbell will be with you *shortly*.

There is no connotation of length of time associated with 'directly' in this context, but it is most often used when the length of wait is not expected to be excessive. A few hours is OK, but if someone is going to be waiting for 3 days, you probably wouldn't use 'directly.'

For longer waits in the South, *after'while* is more acceptable.

> Well, I reckon we'll be a'fixin granddaddy's tractor *after'while*.